# Getting error while fetching the column values from cursor object in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to fetch the column values from Cursor object and use them into select statement with aggregate function and group by clause and put the data into another table but getting error.

**Code**

```
sql10 = f"""SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM tablename ORDER BY col4 ;"""
select_snow =cs.execute(sql10).fetchall()
snow_col = [(c[1],c[2]) for c in select_snow]
cursor.fast_executemany = True
sql17 = f"INSERT INTO newtable(col11,col12) (SELECT ?,MAX(?) FROM select_snow GROUP BY ?);"
```

**Error**

"ERROR: Unexpected error! - ('Expected 3 parameters, supplied 2', 'HY000')"

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the column metadata using **description** method:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table")
print(','.join([col[0] for col in cur.description]))
```

Have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#retrieving-column-metadata) for more information.

For your particular case:

```
query = """
select RIDE_ID,RIDEABLE_TYPE,STARTED_AT,ENDED_AT,START_STATION_NAME,END_STATION_NAME from citibike_trips order by ride_id limit 1;
"""

try:
    select_snow=cs.execute(query).fetchall()
    print(select_snow)
    print(','.join([col[0] for col in cs.description]))
finally:
    cs.close()
```

I get back:

```
[('000008096013E2D5', 'docked_bike', datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 21, 18, 59, 49), datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 21, 19, 11, 31), 'E 39 St & Lexington Ave', 'Christopher St & Greenwich St')]
RIDE_ID,RIDEABLE_TYPE,STARTED_AT,ENDED_AT,START_STATION_NAME,END_STATION_NAME
```

You can see that **select_snow** just holds values so you can't get the column names out of it. You need to use the **description** method.

Comment: I am using select_snow which will further will be used in code. So I can't remove select_snow from the code.

Comment: What is select_snow? I am not familiar with it and doesn't seem to belong to Snowflake..

Comment: It is just an variable. I have edit the question with more details and code I am using

Comment: Your select_snow holds only values, no metadata so you can't retrieve column names from it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am looking column name and column value. I have given the code

Comment: I want few columns not all the columns

Comment: I only got back the columns I selected not all from the row. My select contains only a few columns, table has a lot more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248176/discussion-between-naveen-and-sergiu).